# Filter rows based on grouped matching in multiple rows / columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements

new to asking a question. Please be kind. If my example doesn't help, let me know and I'll try to create something better.

I want to filter a data frame like this:

```r
df <- tibble(
  species=c("Abies", "Abies", "Abies", "Abies", "Abrus", "Abrus", "Abrus", "Acacia", "Acacia", "Acacia", "Acacia", "Acacia"), 
  native_region=c(4,4,4,3,2,2,2,4,5,6,8,8), 
  invasive=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1), 
  intro_region=c(8,3,4,5,3,6,7,5,7,7,7,7)
  )
```

so that two things happen:

1. check the rows (grouped by species) where any intro_region value is the same as any native_region value. Filter out the rows where those values are present in the intro_region column;

EDIT: native_region values cannot exist in any intro_region column (in species groups)

such as (but this code below doesn't actually work):

```r
df %>% group_by(species) %>% filter(., all(native_region != intro_region))
```

EDIT: output like this:

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  species native_region invasive intro_region
  <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Abies               4        1            8
2 Abies               3        1            5
3 Abrus               2        0            3
4 Abrus               2        0            6
5 Abrus               2        1            7
6 Acacia              5        0            7
7 Acacia              6        1            7
8 Acacia              8        0            7
9 Acacia              8        1            7
```

2. and check rows (grouped by species) where intro_region is duplicated but invasive is 1 in some rows and 0 in others. Filter out the rows with a 0 value in invasive; such as (but this code obviously doesn't work either):

EDIT: for intro_region, if there is a row where invasive = 0 and a row where invasive = 1, keep only the row with 1.

```r
df %>% group_by(species, intro_region) %>% filter(invasive!=0 & invasive == 1)
```

kinda like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759658/filter-rows-within-groups-based-on-multiple-conditions) question.

EDIT: so that df looks like this:

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  species native_region invasive intro_region
  <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Abies               4        1            8
2 Abies               3        1            5
3 Abrus               2        0            3
4 Abrus               2        0            6
5 Abrus               2        1            7
6 Acacia              6        1            7
7 Acacia              8        1            7
```

Thanks for any help you can give me! And thanks to those old skoolers like @akrun who've indirectly taught me R. You are in my PhD acknowledgment section. Seriously you are.

Comment: @RonakShah I added an desired output after condition 1. hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help with the second part.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(species, native_region, intro_region) %>% 
  filter(all(c(1,0) %in% invasive)) %>% 
  filter(., invasive == 0) %>% 
  anti_join(df, .)  

# A tibble: 11 × 4
   species native_region invasive intro_region
   <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 Abies               4        1            8
 2 Abies               4        1            3
 3 Abies               4        1            4
 4 Abies               3        1            5
 5 Abrus               2        0            3
 6 Abrus               2        0            6
 7 Abrus               2        1            7
 8 Acacia              4        1            5
 9 Acacia              5        0            7
10 Acacia              6        1            7
11 Acacia              8        1            7

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the first part:

```r
df %>% select(species, native_region) -> x
df %>% group_by(species) %>% anti_join(., x, by = c("species", "intro_region" = "native_region"))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   species [3]
  species native_region invasive intro_region
  <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Abies               4        1            8
2 Abies               3        1            5
3 Abrus               2        0            3
4 Abrus               2        0            6
5 Abrus               2        1            7
6 Acacia              5        0            7
7 Acacia              6        1            7
8 Acacia              8        0            7
9 Acacia              8        1            7
```

Boom.

I'll still take suggestions on the second part. Thanks to everyone.